# Special RewriteRule in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

In my wordpress installation I have a special page which gets data from an external database.

If I open http://localhost/o-b/comm/?id=123 everthing works fine. But if I open http://localhost/ob/comm/123 Wordpress leads me to a 404 error page. I've checked the RewriteRule with an online rewrite rule check and I get a match.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^ob/comm/(.*)$ o-b/comm/?id=$1 #this line is killing me

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Any hints on that?

Comment: Forgot to say: All other rewrite like permalinks etc is working.

Comment: I think you need to add the `[L]` flag on the end of the rule.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the permalinks option under Setting in the WordPress Dashboard to find the option to do this.

Not sure what does variable "id" mean here, because it's normally "p", if this is custom post type, the url rewrite needs to turned on for it.

read more here:
https://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks